# Building Apache modules separately without rebuilding all of Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an operational and compiled from source Apache installation with shared modules enabled.

I now want to use `mod_proxy` but at the time I built my Apache server I didn't know I would need this and I didn't specify  `--enable-mod_proxy=shared` and  `--enable-mod_proxy_http=shared` when I ran `./configure`.

On [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/dso.html) it suggests that I can do:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/path/to/install --enable-foo=shared
$ make install
```

Will this **only** build the module specified and install it to the `--prefix` path, or will it rebuild all of Apache and redeploy that too?

Comment: @TomO'Connor - CentOS 5/6 but our builds are somewhat customised for our particular environment.

Comment: @TomO'Connor Some even use FreeBSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `mod_proxy/mod_proxy_http` compiles with `apxs` works just fine:

```
apxs -i -c mod_proxy.c proxy_util.c
apxs -i -c mod_proxy_http.c
```

Comment: @TomO'Connor - thanks :), don't know why I didn't think of that in the first place.